# Why do infinite loops delay printing?

Tags: c++, c++11

This is a backstory, you can skip to the question in bold below if you don't wanna read it.

Recently while solving a problem I accidentally had an infinite loop in it. But I didn't know so I tried to debug the code, and obviously a good way to debug ( or at least a way that I'm used to ) is to place a few flags in the code, that would print to the console that the program has finished successfully until that part. But later I saw that even when I place the flag as the first thing in the program, it still wouldn't print anything. I managed to fin the bug by using return 0 instead of placing flags, but this got me wondering,

**Why doesn't the following program print "A" right away?**

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    cout<<"A";
    int k=1;
    while(k)k++;
}
```

**Edit:** Even after changing the `cout<<"A";` into `cout<<"A"<<endl;` the problem continued existing.
I'm using C++ 14 GNU GCC compiler

Answer (score 2):

That is because output is buffered by default, so you are leaving it up to the program to decide when it will actually render your output to the screen.

If you force it by using `cout<<"A"<<endl;`, you will get an immediate flush and a print, as you expect.

Comment: I just tried it, it is still delayed.

Comment: @MartinDinev if that was not clear I meant `cout<<"A"<<endl;`

Comment: You were clear, that's what I did.

Comment: @MartinDinev then I can't reproduce, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I'm using C++ 14 GNU GCC compiler

Comment: @MartinDinev Me too, sorry, you are experiencing some weird behavior. Maybe try a clean environment (maybe you are somehow not overwriting the executable?). `fflush()` will also force a flush, and if you can't get these to work may be worth another SO question including your compiler, OS and so forth.